# changing line angle in scale_pattern_manual in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggpattern

I would like change the patterns in my stacked barchart using `scale_pattern_manual` to have the last stack in my stacked barchart have vertical lines instead of horizontal 45 degrees. So I want them to be 45 degree horizontal lines, crosshatch, 180 degree vertical lines. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried to add `pattern_angle = c(45, 45, 180)` inside  `geom_col_pattern()` but am getting an error as it will only let me add one angle (i.e., pattern_angle = 180) which will change the line angle for all three variables.

[image]

```
set.seed(687532)                     # Create example data frame
data <- data.frame(facet = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 6),
                   group = c("x", "y"),
                   stack = letters[1:3],
                   value = round(abs(rnorm(30)), 2))
data  

ggplot(data,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = group,
           y = value,
           fill = stack)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = 0.6) + 
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
                          text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
  ) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance(%)"))) + 
  facet_wrap(~facet, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") + theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
                                             plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.3, 0.3)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey')) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "stack",
    values = c('stripe', 'crosshatch', 'stripe')
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = stack),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black",
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by mapping on the `pattern_angle` aesthetic and setting your desired angles via `scale_pattern_angle_manual`:

Note: For the sake of visibility I have used `pattern_fill = "red"` and `pattern_spacing = .05`. And as a general note: `geom_col_pattern` is a substitute for `geom_col` or `geom_bar`, i.e. there is no need to add duplicated layers.

```
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data,
  aes(
    x = group,
    y = value,
    fill = stack
  )
) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = stack, pattern_angle = stack),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .05,
    pattern_fill = "red",
    color = "black",
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.3, 0.3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "lightgrey", "darkgrey")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "stack",
    values = c("stripe", "crosshatch", "stripe")
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "stack",
    values = c(45, 30, 90)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~facet, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA, size = 0),
    text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)
  ) +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance(%)")))
```

[image]